# How do I hide an entire HTML page, but make the page still renders and still exist?

Tags: javascript, html, hide, visibility, visibilitychange

I'm making an extension to hide the ChromeOS bookshelf by displaying a completely hidden tab, so the device would register a window being drawn, but the user could not interact or notice it.

This is one of my first coding projects, and I've gone through 5 or so iterations, any help would be appreciated because I'm running out of search results to try and I have very little coding experience.

tab.hide() for Firefox: I don't want to use this, because it would be too much work for a user to do every time they needed to start/fix the extension.

DOM Manipulation is possible, but I don't have experience with python and ASP.net.

Moving the window offscreen doesn't work because the tab stays onscreen and can't move off.
Setting the background and all of the elements transparent doesn't make it 100% transparent, and keeps the search bar.

If you need more info, I have all of my files on my GitHub, just ask and I can make my repository public.

Comment: You can use `chrome.windows.create()` to set the `width` and `height` to `1`, something like this https://github.com/guest271314/sw-extension-audio/blob/main/background.js#L7-L15

Comment: The project is finished, it's not pretty but it works.
Thank you for the help @guest271314
https://github.com/grumpyman12601/bookshelf